# Android Studio Intent runtime error

Tags: android

So I have two main parts; MainActivity and SecondaryActivity.
I created a button on MainActivity that would lead to SecondaryActivity and send/display a message.
The button does redirect to SecondaryActivity, but the message is not sent/shown. I think it might have to do with the getIntent() usage, but I'm not sure. I'm new at this!

MainActivity:

```
package divadi.hour2application;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    Button activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //add code here for button click
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondaryActivity.class);
                startIntent.putExtra("com.talkingandroid,MESSAGE","Hello SecondaryActivity");
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

SecondaryActivity:

```
package divadi.hour2application;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.talkingandroid.MESSAGE");
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    messageTextView.setText(message);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have a "," when sending but a "." when receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your close.  You just mistyped the key when you are putting the value into the intent.

Here we send `com.talkingandroid,MESSAGE` note the `,`

```
startIntent.putExtra("com.talkingandroid,MESSAGE","Hello SecondaryActivity");
```

and in the next activity we are looking for the same string but with a `.`

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.talkingandroid.MESSAGE");
```

If you just create a `public static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "myMessageKey";` somewhere you can avoid this in the future.

Comment: Ahhh I completely missed that! Thank you so much for your help, but one more question: would the code work if I changed 'Intent intent = getIntent();' to 'Intent= getIntent();' and capitalize the intent on the next line?

Comment: Intent = getIntent();

        String message = Intent.getStringExtra("com.talkingandroid.MESSAGE");    That was how it was written in the book, but I keep getting the error "cannot find symbol variable Intent". How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't capitilize the second `intent`.  When you do it will find the `Intent` class instead of your variable.  the `Intent#getStringExtra` method is not static so you cannot access it through the `Intent` class reference

Comment: Ah, I get it! 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Java convention is to use `camelCase` for variables and using `WordCase` for classes.  So using the first letter as upper case for variables will lead to this problem.  Glad to help. please accept the answer if your satisfied.